# I want cases in status "Scanned" for 24 hours to be escalated to supervisors, so that they're aware that action needs to take place

Tags: process-builder, casefeed

Given a Case is in an “scanned” status, WHEN the age of the Case exceeds 24 hours, Then a Chatter notification is issued to user’s in the Role.

I was using Case escalation rule by setting the hours as org default(our business hours are 24 hours every day) and I am using process builder for scheduling time actions to post to chatter. Is there any other possible way to notify users??

Comment: you can send emails to them. using time-triggered automation

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_notificationbuilder.htm

Comment: You can notify them this is new in the latest release

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty I find it useful but what I am thinking is How can I post the notification to different User's at the same time is it possible?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_action_addcustomnotification.htm&type=5

Comment: It can be user, Group or queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sai,

You can use the notification process see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_action_customnotification.htm&type=5) It can support User, Queue and group so it can go to multiple users if you use Group or Queue. This is a native way to notify users.